# Android Studio Logcat to read/open saved logs

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, logging, logcat

I saved some logs and would like to open them with Android Studio - Logcat interface and be able to see the colours and apply some filters just as if the phone was connected.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

What I normally do when I need to visualise different logcats is, I open them at Visual Studio Code and apply ***"Log"*** language mode.
With ***"Log"*** language mode you can see all the log colors.

Answer (score 0):

You can paste saved logs into Code -> Analyze Stack Trace or Thread Dump